# What Event Fires When a TabPage is Displayed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a TabControl with several TabPages in a Form. Loading the Form is rather quick and not an issue. However, when I click on the second `TabPage` in the `TabControl`, it takes about 10 seconds for the UI to show it. That `TabPage` contains a `DataGridView` with 7000+ items. I'm not concerned at all with the time required to render the UI for the second `TabPage`. I just want to get a `WaitCursor` going, so users know to wait as the system is preparing to display the `TabPage` on-screen.

I've determined that the `TabControl.Selecting` event is where I can set a WaitCursor. But I can't for the life of me find an event that says "This TabPage with the big DataGridView is now displayed on-screen."

I've tried the following events to no avail:

- TabControl.Selected (fires way too early, before the second tab is even rendered on-screen)
- TabPage.GotFocus (the actual TabPage never gets the focus)
- TabPage.Enter (doesn't fire the event)
- TabPage.Layout (fires several times on Form.Load and also after rendering the TabPage on-screen)

I've discovered that `TabPage.Paint` is an event that I can use to reset the Cursor to Cursors.Default, but that seems hacky and out of place, since I'm not actually painting anything myself. Is there any other (proper?) event that raises when the `TabPage` is rendered on-screen, or is `.Paint` really what I'm looking for, and I just answered my own question?

Comment: why not put a spinner on that page and show that its loading?

Comment: Do these tabpages consist of actual classes and or other composite UC(user control)? Typically you would create an async task to load these things all while throwing up a loading window. Without anything to go on, help is scarce...

Comment: If you have not, you should read through the [TabControl.Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) section.  Your statement that the `Enter` event does not fire is strange.  Also, 7000 items in a DGV should not be a factor in displaying it unless you are unnecessarily assigning visual state properties to each cell instead of using the CellFormatting event to adjust visual characteristics when needed. The DGV only needs to format cells that are visible at a given moment and typically the visible cells are small in number.

Comment: @DanielA.White the page is already loaded. It's just clicking the Tab that causes a 10 second delay until that TabPage is drawn on-screen.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ same comment, the page, DataGridView, etc. are already loaded and the form is shown. Just clicking the TabPage is causing a 10 second delay.